# Null Pointer Exception while converting Temperature from Celcius to Farenheit in android

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, weather

I am trying to convert the temperature from celcius to farenheit(C to F) in Settings Page for weather app. once i click the toggle button to "C" or "F" and press "SAVE" button the app gets crashed and force closes, instead after the convert, it should display the result in MainActivity.java screen. The error in the logcat tells that this is due to "Null Pointer" Exception, but i have declared all the varible correctly. Please help me to rectify this issue. Thanks.

Here's the code.
this is the line which gets null pointer exception

```
String ccmin1 =data.getStringExtra("cmin1");
```

..

```
 public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity  implements OnClickListener {
 private TextView tempmin1;
```

Logcat Error.

```
 01-15 13:37:25.287: E/AndroidRuntime(602): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure  delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=1, data=Intent { (has extras) }}   to activity {com.weather/com.weather.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 01-15 13:37:25.287: E/AndroidRuntime(602):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
 01-15 13:37:25.287: E/AndroidRuntime(602):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2574)
 01-15 13:37:25.287: E/AndroidRuntime(602):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
 01-15 13:37:25.287: E/AndroidRuntime(602):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:961)
 01-15 13:37:25.287: E/AndroidRuntime(602):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 01-15 13:37:25.287: E/AndroidRuntime(602):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 01-15 13:37:25.287: E/AndroidRuntime(602):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
 01-15 13:37:25.287: E/AndroidRuntime(602):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 01-15 13:37:25.287: E/AndroidRuntime(602):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 01-15 13:37:25.287: E/AndroidRuntime(602):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
 01-15 13:37:25.287: E/AndroidRuntime(602):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
 01-15 13:37:25.287: E/AndroidRuntime(602):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 01-15 13:37:25.287: E/AndroidRuntime(602): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  01-15 13:37:25.287: E/AndroidRuntime(602):    at com.weather.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:922)
  01-15 13:37:25.287: E/AndroidRuntime(602):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
```

Settings.java code

```
public class Settings extends SherlockActivity {
MainActivity mActivity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);
    mActivity = new MainActivity();

 Intent intent = getIntent();

    final String YourtransferredData =intent.getStringExtra("YourValueKey");
    final String tempData =intent.getStringExtra("temp");
    final String WwindData =intent.getStringExtra("windspeed");
    final String tempfvalue = intent.getStringExtra("Tempf");
    final String PressureData = intent.getStringExtra("pressure");
    final String tempfmin1 = intent.getStringExtra("tempfmin1");
    final String tempfmax1 = intent.getStringExtra("tempfmax1");
    final String tempcmin1 = intent.getStringExtra("tempcmin1");
    final String tempcmax1 = intent.getStringExtra("tempcmax1");
    final String tempFFFmin1 = intent.getStringExtra("tempFFmin1");
    final String tempFFFmin2 = intent.getStringExtra("tempFFmin2");
    final String tempFFFmin3 = intent.getStringExtra("tempFFmin3");
    final String tempFFFmin4 = intent.getStringExtra("tempFFmin4");
    final String tempFFFmax1 = intent.getStringExtra("tempFFmax1");
    final String tempFFFmax2 = intent.getStringExtra("tempFFmax2");
    final String tempFFFmax3 = intent.getStringExtra("tempFFmax3");
    final String tempFFFmax4 = intent.getStringExtra("tempFFmax4");
    final String tempCCCmin1 = intent.getStringExtra("tempCCmin1");
    final String tempCCCmin2 = intent.getStringExtra("tempCCmin2");
    final String tempCCCmin3 = intent.getStringExtra("tempCCmin3");
    final String tempCCCmin4 = intent.getStringExtra("tempCCmin3");
    final String tempCCCmax1 = intent.getStringExtra("tempCCmax1");
    final String tempCCCmax2 = intent.getStringExtra("tempCCmax2");
    final String tempCCCmax3 = intent.getStringExtra("tempCCmax3");
    final String tempCCCmax4 = intent.getStringExtra("tempCCmax4");

    Log.d("tempfvalue111","welcome all "+getIntent().getStringExtra("YourValueKey")+tempData+WwindData+tempfvalue+PressureData);     
    //Log.d("tempfvalue","Value");     
    final Button mNotification_tempc=(Button)findViewById(R.id.tempc);
    final Button mNotification_tempf=(Button)findViewById(R.id.tempf);
    final Button mNotification_wmph=(Button)findViewById(R.id.wmph);
    final Button mNotification_wms=(Button)findViewById(R.id.wms);
    final Button mNotification_wkm=(Button)findViewById(R.id.wkm);
    /*final Button mNotification_pinches=(Button)findViewById(R.id.pinches);
    final Button mNotification_pmm=(Button)findViewById(R.id.pmm);
    final Button mNotification_pmbar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.pmbar);*/
    final Button done =(Button)findViewById(R.id.done);

    TextView header = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textheader);
    header.setText("Please choose the Settings your personalized settings");

    mNotification_tempc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   // mNotification_on_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mNotification_tempc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    String state =  mNotification_tempc.getText().toString(); 
                    Toast.makeText(Settings.this,
                            "Toggle State :" + state, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("OnCclick",tempData); 
                   // mNotification_tempc.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                   // mNotification_tempf.setEnabled(false); 
                    Intent intent1=new Intent();  
                   intent1.putExtra("TEMPC",tempData); 
                   intent1.putExtra("cmin",tempcmin1);
                    intent1.putExtra("cmax",tempcmax1);
                    intent1.putExtra("cmin1",tempCCCmin1);
                    intent1.putExtra("cmin2",tempCCCmin2);
                    intent1.putExtra("cmin3",tempCCCmin3);
                    intent1.putExtra("cmin4",tempCCCmin4);
                    intent1.putExtra("cmax1",tempCCCmax1);
                    intent1.putExtra("cmax2",tempCCCmax2);
                    intent1.putExtra("cmax3",tempCCCmax3);
                    intent1.putExtra("cmax4",tempCCCmax4);
                   setResult(1,intent1);  


                }
            });

        mNotification_tempf.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   // mNotification_off_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mNotification_tempf.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    String state =  mNotification_tempf.getText().toString(); 
                    Toast.makeText(Settings.this,
                            "Toggle State :" + state, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent=new Intent();  
                    intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",tempfvalue);  
                    intent.putExtra("fmin",tempfmin1);
                    intent.putExtra("fmax",tempfmax1);
                    intent.putExtra("fmin1",tempFFFmin1);
                    intent.putExtra("fmin2",tempFFFmin2);
                    intent.putExtra("fmin3",tempFFFmin3);
                    intent.putExtra("fmin4",tempFFFmin4);
                    intent.putExtra("fmax1",tempFFFmax1);
                    intent.putExtra("fmax2",tempFFFmax2);
                    intent.putExtra("fmax3",tempFFFmax3);
                    intent.putExtra("fmax4",tempFFFmax4);
                    setResult(2,intent);  
                   // mNotification_tempf.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                  //  mNotification_tempc.setPressed(true);; 
                        //  mActivity.setTextView3(tempfvalue); 
                   // mActivity.temp1.setText(tempfvalue+"\u00B0"+"F");;


                }
            });
    done.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            }
        });
            }
```

onActivityResult Code

```
@Override  
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
   {  
             super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  

              // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2  



    if(resultCode==2)  

               {   
                    String message=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");   
                    String fminv= data.getStringExtra("fmin");
                    String fmaxv= data.getStringExtra("fmax");
                    String ffmin1 =data.getStringExtra("fmin1");
                    String ffmin2 =data.getStringExtra("fmin2");
                    String ffmin3 =data.getStringExtra("fmin3");
                    String ffmin4 =data.getStringExtra("fmin4");
                    String ffmax1 =data.getStringExtra("fmax1");
                    String ffmax2 =data.getStringExtra("fmax2");
                    String ffmax3 =data.getStringExtra("fmax3");
                    String ffmax4 =data.getStringExtra("fmax4");
                    temp1.setText(message);  
                    minvalue.setText(fminv); 
                    maxvalue.setText(fmaxv);  
                    tempmin1.setText(ffmin1);   
                    Log.d("jesus",ffmin1);
                    tempmin2.setText(ffmin2);
                    Log.d("jesus2",ffmin2);
                    tempmin3.setText(ffmin3);
                    tempmin4.setText(ffmin4);
                    tempmax1.setText(ffmax1);
                    tempmax2.setText(ffmax2);
                    tempmax3.setText(ffmax3);
                    tempmax4.setText(ffmax4);
                    Log.d("jesus4",ffmin2);
              }  

if( resultCode==1)
{
String message1=data.getStringExtra("TEMPC");
String cminv= data.getStringExtra("cmin");
String cmaxv= data.getStringExtra("cmax");
String ccmin1 =data.getStringExtra("cmin1");
String ccmin2 =data.getStringExtra("cmin2");
String ccmin3 =data.getStringExtra("cmin3");
String ccmin4 =data.getStringExtra("cmin4");
String ccmax1= data.getStringExtra("cmax1");
String ccmax2= data.getStringExtra("cmax2");
String ccmax3= data.getStringExtra("cmax3");
String ccmax4= data.getStringExtra("cmax4");

temp1.setText(message1);
minvalue.setText(cminv); 
maxvalue.setText(cmaxv);
tempmin1.setText(ccmin1);
tempmin2.setText(ccmin2);
tempmin3.setText(ccmin3);
tempmin4.setText(ccmin4);
tempmax1.setText(ccmax1);
tempmax2.setText(ccmax2);
tempmax3.setText(ccmax3);
tempmax4.setText(ccmax4);

}
```

Comment: Take a look at com.weather.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:922), debug and set a breakpoint.

Comment: Post your code block of onActivityResult

Comment: `String ccmin1 =data.getStringExtra("cmin1");` you said in this line you are getting `NullPointerException` .. Then what is `data` here if it is an object its having null value.

Comment: most likely `tempCCCmin1` is null, meaning `intent.getStringExtra("tempCCmin1");` is null, meaning you never put a tempCCmin1 extra when calling Settings

Comment: updated onActivityResult code. @Arju

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you get the String `"cmin1"` is passed from previous activity, Also check spelling

`String ccmin1 =data.getStringExtra("cmin1");`

If any of the tags `fmin2` `fmin3` is not passed from previous activity it will cause `NPE`

**UPDATE** 
I think you have a problem with `resultCode` and `requestCode`

Always check `if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)`

and `requestCode` is the one you pass